# Example of a circular reference in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I was wondering if anyone has a good, working example of a circular reference in javascript?  I know this is incredibly easy to do with closures, but have had a hard time wrapping my brain around this.  An example that I can dissect in Firebug would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answers; I can see Josh's example happening in a production app where I might have many bound events.  I would love to prevent this leakage from happening on my clients that are running IE6.  Correct me if I'm wrong but this is only an issue with browsers IE6 and below?  Most modern browsers implement a garbage collector capable of finding these type of references?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

A simple way to create a circular reference is to have an object that refers to itself in a property:

```
function Foo() {
  this.abc = "Hello";
  this.circular = this;
}

var foo = new Foo();
alert(foo.circular.circular.circular.circular.circular.abc);
```

Here the `foo` object contains a reference to itself.

With closures this is usually more implicit, by just having the circular reference in scope, not as an explicit property of some object:

```
var circular;

circular = function(arg) {
  if (arg) {
    alert(arg);
  }
  else {
    // refers to the |circular| variable, and by that to itself.
    circular("No argument");
  }
}

circular("hello");
circular();
```

Here the function saved in `circular` refers to the `circular` variable, and thereby to itself. It implicitly holds a reference to itself, creating a circular reference. Even if `circular` now goes out of scope, it is still referenced from the functions scope. Simple garbage collectors won't recognize this loop and won't collect the function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sth.  It's a very simple example that's easy to understand.

Comment: What is the benefit of "Simple garbage collectors won't recognize this loop and won't collect the function"? In your example here, does it mean `circular` is always accessible and can be updated? I ask because my API has a circular object that carries database transaction context, so it seems like it would be updated all the time with new context info, so avoiding garbage collection seems like a good plan. Am I close?

Comment: And just for some extra complete information, I noticed that it throws a circular reference error if I try to snapshot it with `console.log(JSON.stringify(circular))`. I'm curious why I can't view it in this manner to see the current context.

Comment: "*Simple garbage collectors won't recognize this loop and won't collect the function.*" - C'mon, something that isn't able to deal with reference circles can't earn the name *garbage collector*.

Answer (score 26):

Or even simpler, an array "containing" itself. See example:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = arr;
```

Answer (score 20):

Probably the shortest way to define a cyclic object.

```
a = {}; a.a = a;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
window.onload = function() {
  hookup(document.getElementById('menu'));

  function hookup(elem) {
    elem.attachEvent( "onmouseover", mouse);

    function mouse() {
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the handler is nested within the attacher, which means it is closed over the scope of the caller.

Comment: Thanks Josh, seems like a realistic example of what could happen in an actual app

Comment: @Josh Stodola can you explain why this is a problem? I'm tried to dissect this code and understand why this would cause a memory leak. Thanks.

Comment: @Amir in order to attach mouse() function DOM object must refer to whole hookup function and attachEvent is inside this hookup function and this makes circular reference more details here
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/830555

Answer (score 4):

Or using ES6:

```
class Circular {
  constructor() {
    this.value = "Hello World";
    this.self = this;
  }
}

circular = new Circular();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

- `window.window...window`
- `var circle = {}; circle.circle = circle;`
- `var circle = []; circle[0] = circle; or circle.push(circle)`
- `function Circle(){this.self = this}; var circle = new Circle()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var b = [];
var a = [];
a[0] = b;
b[0] = a;
```

Printing `a` or `b` would return `Circular`.

Comment: That is a circular reference, but what do you mean by "printing"? Your answer implies the JS engine would actually return the string "Circular"...

Comment: He means if you `console.log(a)` then it prints `[ [ [Circular] ] ]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function circular(arg){
    var count = 0;

    function next(arg){
        count++;
        if(count > 10) return;
        if(arg){
            console.log('hava arg: ' + arg);
            next();
        }else{
            console.log('no arg');
            next('add');
        }
    }
    next();
}
circular();
```

Circular and with a closures.