# Where is the circular reference in this code?

Tags: javascript, circular-reference

I have a table where I can add images onclick. The table is created dynamically from a form. I have tried to save the table to local storage, but I am getting a circular reference issue. I have read this [Example of a circular reference in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493453/example-of-a-circular-reference-in-javascript) but I am a complete novice and struggling to understand. Can you point it out to me?

```
function makeChart() {
        var table = document.createElement('table'),
        taskName = document.getElementById('taskname').value,
        header = document.createElement('th'),
        numDays = document.getElementById('days').value, //columns
        howOften = document.getElementById('times').value, //rows
        row,
        r,
        col,
        c;



    var cel = null;
    var myImages = new Array();
    myImages[0] = "http://www.olsug.org/wiki/images/9/95/Tux-small.png";
    myImages[1] = "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1139237954/just-logo_normal.png";
    var my_div = document.createElement("div");
    my_div.id = "showPics";
    document.body.appendChild(my_div);
    var newList = document.createElement("ul");
    my_div.appendChild(newList);

    if (taskName == '' || numDays == '') {
        alert('Please enter task name and number of days');
    }
    if (howOften == '') {
        howOften = 1;
    }
    if (taskName != '' && numDays != '') {

        for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
            var allImages = new Image();
            allImages.src = myImages[i];
            allImages.onclick = function (e) {
                if (sel !== null) {
                    sel.src = e.target.src;

                    my_div.style.display = 'none';
                    sel.onclick = null;
                    sel = null;
                }
            };

            var li = document.createElement('ul');
            li.appendChild(allImages);
            newList.appendChild(li);
        }
        my_div.style.display = 'none';

        header.innerHTML = taskName;
        table.appendChild(header);

        function addImage(col) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-adobe.png";
            col.appendChild(img);
            img.onclick = function () {
                my_div.style.display = 'block';
                sel = img;
            };
        }
        for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
            row = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
                col = row.insertCell(-1);
                addImage(col);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('holdTable').appendChild(table);
        document.getElementById('createChart').onclick = null;
        console.log(table);
        localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(table));
        console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( table ) ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: All DOM elements contain circular references (for example via `parentNode.childNodes…`. Serialize them to HTML, instead of trying JSON stringification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any DOM element holds a reference to the `parentNode` and to the `document`, which you can't stringify. In fact each element holds a link to it parent which holds links to its childs.

You can't apply `JSON.stringify` to a DOM element.

If you really want to save your table, you could save its HTML using `table.innerHTML`. We could propose other solutions (there even are specific stringify implementations able to produce JSON from circular elements or DOM nodes). But we'd need to know **why** you try to save a table in `localStorage`.

Comment: OK, so if I am understanding correctly it is trying to stringify the whole way back up the DOM so I should target the table like so localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(table.innerHTML)); ? And I  just noticed I should have name as key instead of table in last log.

Comment: You **could** do that, but why ? Serializing a part of the page isn't standard practice.

Comment: That works. The table is unique to different users so I want the user to see their particular table when the enter the page. I'm not sure that I understand what you are getting at. I should save the whole page?

Comment: No, you shouldn't save any HTML. Can't your table be built from a small piece of data that you could save ?

Comment: Are you talking about a cookie or something?

Comment: No, I mean you could simply save an ID of your user in localStorage instead of saving a table. But it entirely depends on your application logic.