# Closure circular reference?

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this piece of code

```js
var obj = {
    foo: 5
};

var recursive = (function(){
    if(this.foo === 0){
        return;
    }

    this.foo--;
    recursive();
}).bind(obj);
```

Does the recursive function create a circular reference? If or if not, why?

**EDIT**: Circular reference between the function `recursive` and itself. I also found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493501/4354420)

Comment: What do you mean by "create"? What entities do you expect to be part of the reference graph?

Comment: *"Does the recursive function create a circular reference?"* Between what and what?

Comment: Between the function `recursive` and itself. I edited the post.

Comment: Why not just try it with an alert()? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=xCifTQpoMU I can not tell you why it's not an endless loop though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the recursive function definition create a circular reference, like [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493501/1048572)?

Yes, it still does. `bind` doesn't change that, although it introduces an additional link in the reference circle.

- The variable `recursive` holds the bound function
- The bound function (created from the `.bind()` call) contains a slot with the original function
- The original function (created from the function expression) closes over the variable scope that contains `recursive`

Comment: How can I redesign it so it avoids a circular reference?

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz You cannot, and you absolutely do not need to.

Comment: Just to be clear, using a function expression is what makes it circular right? If I am to use a function definition without bind: `function recursive(){ recursive(); }` it wouldn't be circular?

Comment: No, whenever a function refers to itself recursively there *must* be a circular reference somewhere, and it's the same for a function declaration. Why do you want to avoid this?

Comment: Not really avoid, but I want to fully understand the concept and the nuances.