# To update a formgroup formcontrol value from different formgroup but I do not to want to change the values permanently(Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

On hovering over the first column in table , a tooltip appears , on click of the button dialog box opens up which has edit json section

I have provided 2 functionalities :-

[*Please select a row from left section in dialog box*]

1) The json can be edited (In this scenario user clicks on row from left section, starts editing the json and without reverting the new changes the user clicks on a different row under left section and again selects back the previously selected row the original json data is preserved)

2) User clicks on row from left section , and starts giving input from the input field (present just above the Add As button) I start updating the 'mTitle' key in the Edit Json section , so here as well once the user clicks on a different row and again comes back to the previously selected row the json 'mTitle' key does not show the original(old) value

*Expected behaviour*

What I was expecting is once the user gives the input , the 'mTitle' key should be updated(which is working) but the the 'mTitle' key should again retain its old value after the Add As New button is clicked or the user clicks on some other row.(same behaviour as in case 1)

**Stackblitz link**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-v6m2tz?file=app%2Falert-dialog%2Falert-dialog.component.ts

Please suggest

alert-dialog.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="jsonform">
            <json-input formControlName="json" name="result"></json-input>
</form>

 <form [formGroup]="submitJsonNameAndForm" class="">
    <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'" class="alertinput">
        <input matInput trim type="text" #alertnamefieldRef formControlName="alertnamefield" placeholder="Custom Alert Name"
            autocomplete="off" (keyup) = "passingAlerTitle(alertnamefieldRef?.value)">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

alert-dialog.component.ts

```
passingAlerTitle(event){
    this.data.data[this.selectedId].conditionals.alert.mTitle = event;
    this.jsonform.setValue({
      json: this.data.data[this.selectedId].conditionals
     });  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement this on add new button

You just need to keep a copy of selected item and use it on your conditions.

Here is the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-bmirr5?file=app/alert-dialog/alert-dialog.component.ts)

At line 59 this.customTitle= _.cloneDeep(this.data.data[this.selectedId]);, when user select from left panel, made a copy in custom title

At line 72, created a temp variable which will keep changed object from jsonData.

At line 73, updated json data with original data which was in customTitle.

At line 74, added temp variable(new Title) to json data (this is row which has been updated, you can use this where ever you want)

Comment: other function will create shallow copy. You can use const cloneFood = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(food)) if your value is not circular. you can see here https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/

Comment: You were saying one more thing :) , if value is not circular , just out of curiosity wanted to understand.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493453/example-of-a-circular-reference-in-javascript basically, an object is referencing itself after 0 or more layer

Comment: added in answer

Comment: Thanks :) , I have accepted the answer , SO will allow me to honor the bounty in 9 hrs will do it, thanks again

Comment: commented there.